# NavigationView height irregular swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a NavigationView and added a title. The problem is it looks weird when I run it.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

The image looks weird. How can I make the navigation height look better just like UIKIt Navigation Bar

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a double-nested `NavigationView`.
The view that you are showing in your example is already being presented from a `NavigationView`, so you don't need to create an additional view.
This is because the navigation view context is preserved when you use a `NavigationLink`.

Try removing it:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI", displayMode: .inline) 
}
```